# How do I complete a cross join with redshift?

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

I have two tables. One has a user ID and a date and another has a list of dates.

```
with first_day as (
select '2020-03-01' AS DAY_CREATED, '123' AS USER_ID
),

date_series as (
SELECT ('2020-02-28'::date + x)::date as day_n,
'one' as join_key
FROM generate_series(1, 30, 1) x
)

SELECT * from first_day cross join date_series
```

I'm getting this error with redshift 
`Error running query: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.`

Can I do a cross join with redshift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, Redshift supports `generete_series()` but only in a very limited way -- on the master processing node.  That basically renders it useless.

Assuming you have a table with enough rows, you can use that:

```
with first_day as (
      select '2020-03-01' AS DAY_CREATED, '123' AS USER_ID
     ),
     date_series as (
      select ('2020-02-28'::date + x)::date as day_n,
             'one' as join_key
      from (select t.*, row_number() over () as x
            from t   -- big enough table
            limit 30
           ) x
select *
from first_day cross join 
     date_series;
```